# Showing stopping time is finite almost surely by a zero-one law

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-walk, stopping-times

Let $S_{n}$ be a symmetric random walk starting at $0$.  That is $S_{n}= \xi_{1} + \cdots \xi_{n}$ where the $\xi_{i}$ are i.i.d. and $P(\xi_{i}=1)=1/2$ and $P(\xi_{i}=-1)=1/2$. I want to be able to show that the following stopping times:

$$\tau := \inf \{n \in \mathbb{N}: S_{n} \notin (a,b) \}$$

are finite almost surely using the martingale convergence theorem and either the Kolmogorov zero-one law or the Hewitt Savage zero-one law.

The idea is to consider the stopped processes:

$S_{n \wedge \tau}$ which are bounded martingales and hence converge to $Y$ almost surely.  In particular, we have that

\begin{align}
\textbf{1}_{\tau = \infty}S_{n \wedge \tau} \to \textbf{1}_{\tau = \infty}Y \\
\end{align}
and therefore:
\begin{align}
\textbf{1}_{\tau = \infty}S_{n} \to \textbf{1}_{\tau = \infty}Y \\
\\
\end{align}
I feel like I should be able to conclude that $\tau < \infty$ almost surely using one of the two zero-one laws above.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that changes the question. I have to rethink the $\tau_{1}$ case, but I think the idea should still be okay for $\tau$